# how to save and update the application after changing to asyncstorage

Tags: android, ios, react-native, asyncstorage

```
render(){
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
if (this.state.isRefreshing) {
  return(
    <Spinner/>
  )
}
return(
  <Container style={style.container}>
    <Content>
      <List dataArray={this.state.list} renderRow={(data) =>
        <ListItem>
          <CheckBox onPress={() => this.saveLang(data.code)} checked={data.checked} />
            <Text style={style.black}> {data.title}</Text>
        </ListItem>
      }/>
    </Content>
  </Container>
)}
```

After saving how to update the state and apply the selected language

```
saveLang(value){
AsyncStorage.setItem("language", value);
this.setState(
  {
    list: [
    {
      'code': 'ru',
      'title': 'Русский',
      'checked': value == 'ru'
    },
    {
      'code': 'en',
      'title': 'English  ',
      'checked': value == 'en'
    }
  ],
  isRefreshing: true,
  }
);
I18n.locale = value;}
```

refresh passes, but I do not know how to update the application in the background mode
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jABTJ.png)

Comment: What needs to happen during your "refreshing" process? Do you just need to know when the `AsyncStorage` has finished setting the `language` key, or is there something else?

Comment: @RobHogan thx for your answer. I need the selected lang to apply, but in order to see the result I reboot my app hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing more about what you want to happen, but `AsyncStorage.setItem` returns a `Promise` so if you need to do something after it has completed, just use `then`:

```
function saveLang(value) {
  AsyncStorage.setItem("language", value).then(() => {
    // Perform your refresh
  });
}
```

Or alternatively, use `async`/`await` syntax:

```
async function saveLang(value) {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem("language", value);
  // Perform your refresh
}
```

Comment: refresh did not help. I use i18n and to see the result after changing the language in the settings, I need to reboot through cmd + R